# How to use Session Variable in MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, session

I tried to execute this query -

```
$sql="INSERT INTO REGISTRATIONS VALUES ('$_SESSION['fname']', '$_SESSION['username']', '$_SESSION['height']', '$_SESSION['image']');";
```

And this one as well -

```
$sql="INSERT INTO REGISTRATIONS VALUES ($_SESSION['fname'], $_SESSION['username'], $_SESSION['height'], $_SESSION['image']);";
```

But both these returns an error. So i stored the session variables into normal php variables. and tried to execute the query -

```
$name = $_SESSION['fname'];
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$height = $_SESSION['height'];
$image = $_SESSION['image'];

$sql="INSERT INTO REGISTRATIONS VALUES ('$name', '$username', '$height', '$image');";
```

And it worked.

But i want to know why the first two didn't work and why we have to save Session into another variable to get it to work?

Please help :)

Comment: would you mention the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Problem

You have have a syntax error in this code

```
$sql = "
    INSERT INTO REGISTRATIONS
    VALUES (
        '$_SESSION['fname']',
        '$_SESSION['username']',
        '$_SESSION['height']',
        '$_SESSION['image']'
    );
";
```

`'$_SESSION['fname']'` is causing an error here. You can't access array indexes inside a string without special syntax (see below).

## Solution

Separate the string and variables with the concatenation operator, `.`

```
$sql = "
    INSERT INTO REGISTRATIONS
    VALUES ('"
    .$_SESSION['fname'].
    "', '"
    .$_SESSION['username'].
    "', '"
    .$_SESSION['height'].
    "','"
    .$_SESSION['image'].
    "');";
```

or use PHP's [variable interpolation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing), see "Complex (curly) syntax".
**This is the prefered way.**

```
$sql = "
    INSERT INTO REGISTRATIONS
    VALUES (
        '{$_SESSION['fname']}',
        '{$_SESSION['username']}',
        '{$_SESSION['height']}',
        '{$_SESSION['image']}'
    );
";
```

Please note, the this only works on double quoted strings.

Comment: Thank you. Well explained. :)

Answer (score 2):

Try these

```
$sql="INSERT INTO REGISTRATIONS VALUES ('".$_SESSION['fname']."', '".$_SESSION['username']."', '".$_SESSION['height']."', '".$_SESSION['image']."')";
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
echo "$_SESSION[name]";
echo "{$_SESSION['name']}";
```

see http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.simple

If you want to have a reason why this was done so, well, I can't help you there. But as always: PHP is old and has evolved a lot, thus introducing inconsistent syntax.

also check how to use associated array inside double quotes

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.foo-bar

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex

Comment: Thanks. Not exactly what i was looking for, but helped in one way. Also thanks for all the links.